# e-mail sending via php

Tags: php, html, forms, email

the file is entitled as `frontend.php`

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Mail</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="backend.php">
  <label>To</label>
  <input type="email" name="reciever">
  <br>
  <label>Subject</label>
  <input type="text" name="subject">
  <br>
  <label>Message</label>
  <input type="text" name="message"/>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send Mail" name="sendMail" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this file is named as "backend.php"

```
<?php

$from = "waqas.sajid.ncm@gmail.com";
$email=$_POST['reciever'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$messge=$_POST['message'];
ini_set("SMTP","aspmx.l.google.com");
mail($email, $subject, $messge, "From:".$from);

?>
```

but its not working...why? and XAMPP is being used.

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: are you trying in localhost ?

Comment: Define "not working". What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? What happens if you add error checking to make sure that the data in being POSTed? And to check the response from the call to `mail`?

Comment: Also do you have the SMTP extension for PHP?

Comment: what Operating System are you running on?

Comment: Look at the maillog, does that tell you anything?

Comment: error is given below hope you can see it. And yes I am trying to send a mail in localhost as mentioned XAMPP is being used for the purpose. And by not working I mean to say that it don't send the mail to specifies address rather gives an error. Hope its clear now.

Comment: its windows 8. And it looks the problem is in php.ini configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Lolx, you can't simply send email form this general method in xampp or local server...
Upload your code on live server and than check it....

Local server don't allow to send email.. you either need some other server or make your code live...

Comment: What if I say I have been doing this and it was working and I have got mails in my Spam and junk folders. Actually problem is in php.ini configuration if you can help out.